# How do I pass self.request.user as update field?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model where the authenticated user is a FK field. I'm running into problems calling self.partial_update via the UpdateModelMixin as user field cannot be null.

I believe this occurs when it fails to update and falls back to creating. How do I pass user=self.request.user as a parameter only when creating?

I tried modifying the request.data dict but it's apparently immutable

Edit: Fields user and a are sort of like a composite primary key for the other fields so I've made them read_only in the serializer. The API never deals with the model_id pk.

```
class MView(generics.UpdateAPIView, mixins.UpdateModelMixin):    
    def get_object(self):
        a_check = self.request.data.get('a') #Other validity checks but I removed it for simplicity
        if a_check:
            return models.M.objects.filter(user=self.request.user,a=a).first()
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            #request.data.update({'user':self.request.user})
            print(request.data)
            return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)

class M(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete='CASCADE')
    ...

class MSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.M
        fields = ('a','b','c')
        read_only_fields = ('user', 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to overwrite the `update` function from mixins.UpdateModelMixin lifeclycle. check update function [link](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py)

```
 def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data={**request.data, user: self.request.user}, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
            # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
            # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
            instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: There's a typo, 'user': self.request.user or it will throw error user is not defined. There's also a problem with this method of replacing the query dict, it seems that transforming it from QueryDict to regular dict messes up bool variables. i.e. `<QueryDict: {'b': ['true'], 'c': ['true']}>` passes the validated_data check but not `{'b': ['true'], 'c': ['true'], 'user': <CustomUser: ***>}` because `[ErrorDetail(string='Must be a valid boolean.', code='invalid')]`

Comment: I've fixed the issue by using request.data.copy() and updating that instead of passing a regular dict. I'm running into another issue where because I'm setting the fields `user` and `a` to read-only, the validated_data function removes both fields so it triggers a non-null constraint error. I can't find the part in the mixin that is responsible for the create function to overwrite this behaviour. Technically I could remove the read-only constraint since I'm updating the object with the same values I used to select but I'm hoping there's another way to fix this.

Comment: Scratch that, it still doesn't work even if I remove the read-only as I haven't overwritten the create method's user field and it still tries to insert the record with a null user_id

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving it by overwriting the create/update methods in the serializer

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = M.objects.create(user=self.context['request'].user,
                                 **validated_data)
        return instance
```